# Maintain aspect ratio of images in Chrome during native lazy-loading

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, lazy-loading

**Update:** It turns out that this is due to a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1045745). I am still looking for *workarounds*.

---

I am trying to use lazy loading in Chrome by setting `loading="lazy"` on `img` elements. I also use the following to let images fit:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Unfortunately, the image placeholder that is shown before the image actually loads has a square aspect ratio in Chrome. It does not follow the aspect ratio set in the `img` element's `width`/`height` attributes. This happens under the following conditions:

- Only in Chrome (not in Firefox 75, which, also supports lazy loading).
- Only when setting `loading="lazy"`. Without this attribute, the aspect ratio is preserved.

**Is there a solution to preserving the aspect ratio of the image, as set in `width`/`height`, even with lazy loading?**

---

[Here's an article](https://n8d.at/native-lazy-loading-images-with-aspect-ratio/) suggesting that what I am doing should work. Please also see the embedded video in the article, saying the same.

---

You can observe the problem with the below example if throttling the network speed using Chrome's developer tools. I include a screen recording to illustrate the problem. I do not want the image size to change after loading because it causes page elements to shift around.

[image]

#### A minimal example

The HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur pretium nibh tellus, ac luctus erat viverra sed. Aliquam sed nisi sed sapien tempus consectetur vestibulum vel diam. Ut vel faucibus metus. Donec non sem et purus luctus dictum nec et elit. Suspendisse et ipsum tortor. Proin eros massa, pulvinar a ante eu, imperdiet consequat dolor. Pellentesque sed lacus nulla. Mauris gravida purus sed facilisis sollicitudin.
</p>
<p>
    <img src="image.png" width="850" height="422" loading="lazy">
</p>
<p>
Vivamus sagittis faucibus elit non feugiat. Curabitur interdum nulla sed ligula pharetra, in faucibus tortor ullamcorper. Curabitur tristique libero in lobortis posuere. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque quis velit sed tellus aliquet dictum. Fusce vitae consectetur lacus. In scelerisque varius euismod. Nunc scelerisque enim quis lacus dignissim tincidunt. Nulla suscipit, odio eu dictum condimentum, massa elit vestibulum leo, ut lobortis dolor felis vel erat. Cras dapibus, nunc eget sollicitudin semper, elit nisl dictum leo, non semper quam nunc consequat augue. Vivamus bibendum mauris sapien, vel sagittis urna consequat ut.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```css
body {
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 20px;
}

img {
    border: solid black;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codesandbox **[DEMO](https://unks7.csb.app/)** *[(source code)](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-visvesvaraya-unks7)*

---

Maybe a classic padding-top hack might help as a *workaround*.

```css
body {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
}

img {
  border: solid black;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@supports (--foo: 1) {
  .aspect,
  .aspect-inline {
    position: relative;
  }

  .aspect {
    padding-top: calc(var(--height) / var(--width) * 100%);
    height: 0;
    display: block;
  }

  .aspect-inline {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .aspect img,
  .aspect-inline img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <picture class="aspect-inline" style="width: 50px; height: 24.8px">
    <img
      src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SII5r.png"
      loading="lazy"
      width="50"
      height="24,8"
    />
  </picture>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur pretium
  nibh tellus, ac luctus erat viverra sed. Aliquam sed nisi sed sapien
  tempus consectetur vestibulum vel diam. Ut vel faucibus metus. Donec non
  sem et purus luctus dictum nec et elit. Suspendisse et ipsum tortor. Proin
  eros massa, pulvinar a ante eu, imperdiet consequat dolor. Pellentesque
  sed lacus nulla. Mauris gravida purus sed facilisis sollicitudin.
</p>
<p>
  <picture class="aspect" style="--width: 850; --height: 422">
    <img
      src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SII5r.png"
      loading="lazy"
      width="850"
      height="422"
    />
  </picture>
</p>
<p>
  Vivamus sagittis faucibus elit non feugiat. Curabitur interdum nulla sed
  ligula pharetra, in faucibus tortor ullamcorper. Curabitur tristique
  libero in lobortis posuere. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
  et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque quis velit sed
  tellus aliquet dictum. Fusce vitae consectetur lacus. In scelerisque
  varius euismod. Nunc scelerisque enim quis lacus dignissim tincidunt.
  Nulla suscipit, odio eu dictum condimentum, massa elit vestibulum leo, ut
  lobortis dolor felis vel erat. Cras dapibus, nunc eget sollicitudin
  semper, elit nisl dictum leo, non semper quam nunc consequat augue.
  Vivamus bibendum mauris sapien, vel sagittis urna consequat ut.
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works quite well. Unfortunately, in my actual application I have a few inline images as well, and I have not yet managed to generate the page in such a way as to make these distinguishable from the standalone images. I was wondering if this could be modified to not conflict with inline images. An example of an inline image is at the start of the first paragraph [here](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#iglcf).

Comment: I've updated the answer, unfortunately, there is no way to properly distinguish "inline" images from others. I'd recommend using classes. But for this particular layout, where all "block" images are always placed in paragraphs as one image, you can use a selector like this `img:first-child:last-child` to select only these images and apply styles for them. https://i.imgur.com/TG7bT5Q.png

Comment: `img:first-child:last-child` <-- Yes, that's the answer!